# How to show that the following integral is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, estimation

For an application I want to show the following claim: 
Let $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in[0,1]$ be two parameters, then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1+\cos(\pi x (y-0.5))|z|^{x}}{1+2\cos(\pi x (y-0.5))|z|^x+|z|^{2x}}\, dz=\infty$$ 
holds true. I have tried to use the facts, that $\lambda:=\pi x (y-0.5)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)(\rightarrow \cos(\lambda)\in(0,1))$ and
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}z^\beta\,dz=\infty\quad\text{iff}\quad \beta>-1$$ but I didn't get it.

Comment: What do we know about $x,y?$  For large $z$, the integrand is about $|z|^{-x}$, so if $x \lt 1$ you are done.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed $x<1$. This was also the plan I wanted to show. But how to show formally that the integrand is about $|z|^{-x}$ for large $z$?

Comment: Just look at the leading terms.  The numerator goes like $|z|^x$ with the cosine constant out front.  The denominator goes like $|z|^{2x}$.  For large $z$ the other terms do not matter.  Convergence is determined by what happens at large $z$ unless there is a non-integrable pole somewhere.